# iTunes 11.2.2 moves song to top after editing

Tags: itunes

When I've finished editing a song attribute (like the title) and hit enter, iTunes moves this song to the top of the browser. It's very jarring and bad for editing a bunch of files in succession. It also occurs if you click outside of the edit box, so it's not specific to pressing enter.

I realize that I can avoid this by bringing up the Info pane for each song and then clicking "next"/"previous" instead, but this is a hassle and it would be great if iTunes did not move the library after editing.

Does anyone know of a fix/hack for this problem? I don't remember it happening in the past, though I don't edit lots of song titles all that often, so it's possible I just never noticed.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the iTunes Coulomb headers.

That brigs up the long list of choices.

Un-check the Date Modified and Added.

Click on Name coulomb and sort alphabetically.

Now after editing it should stay put.

Comment: That doesn't change anything unfortunately. The problem is not that the location of the file in the library is changing. iTunes is just scrolling up so that the file is sitting at the top of the browser window. That's the behavior I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: your Library view is scrolling to the top but the order of the songs remains as you wanted it?

Comment: what is your View options setting?

Comment: My view options sort by setting is whatever it is at the time - depending on whether I'm currently sorting by artist or date added or title etc. But the jumping of the song up to the top of the browser window happens regardless of what I'm sorting by.